# How would I unit test a method with side effects?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Given the following implementation:

```
class Foo {
    public function helper() {
        // Does something with external side effects, like updating
        // a database or altering the file system.
    }

    public function bar() {
        if ($this->helper() === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception(/* ... */);
        }
    }
}
```

How would I unit test `Foo::bar()` without incurring the side effects of `Foo::helper()` during testing?

I know I can mock `Foo` and stub `Foo::helper()`:

```
public function testGoodBar() {
    $mock = $this->getMock('Foo', array('helper'));
    $this->expects($this->once())
        ->method('helper')
        ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

    $this->assertTrue($mock->bar());
}
```

...but this leaves the test wide open for code changes that introduce other methods which may have side effects.  Then if the test is run again without being updated, the test itself will have permanent side effects.

I could also mock `Foo`, such that all its methods get mocked and won't produce side effects:

```
public function testGoodBar() {
    $mock = $this->getMock('Foo');
    $this->expects($this->once())
        ->method('helper')
        ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

    $this->assertTrue($mock->bar());
}
```

...but then even `Foo::bar()` gets mocked, which is bad, since that's the method we want to test.

The only solution I could come up with is explicitly mocking all methods *except* the one under test:

```
public function testGoodBar() {
    $mock = $this->getMock('Foo', array_diff(
        get_class_methods('Foo'),
        'bar'
    ));

    $this->expects($this->once())
        ->method('helper')
        ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

    $this->assertTrue($mock->bar());
}
```

...but this seems kludgy, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: How are you testing `Foo::helper` itself? Can you mock the external resource it modifies? If not, is there really no way to rewrite `Foo` so it's mockable? If you have a way to test `Foo::helper`, why is `Foo::bar` such a big problem?

Comment: In practice `Foo` is extending the native PHP class `Memcached`, and `Foo::helper()` is `Memcached::flush()` (though the same problem applies to other methods).  So, I'm not testing the helper method, since it isn't my code.  As far as I know, I can't mock the resource either.

Comment: In that case, I rely on the libraries to be tested. I don't test external libraries from within the code I'm using them. Their tests should be in their own projects. So, make sure you use libraries with good test coverage on them. Memcached is pretty vetted in the wild right? So it's probably pretty safe.

Comment: @ThomasSchultz:  I don't think you understand my question.  I'm not concerned with testing the helper methods, or any of the functionality they provide.  I'm only interested in testing my own code (`Foo::bar()` in my examples) without incurring external side effect(s) from any helper methods that _my code_ uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>(Take the comments under the question into consideration for this answer.)</sub>

If you're extending a class whose sole purpose is to have side effects, I'd expect all of the extension code to also produce side effects. Hence you'll have to account for that in your tests and set up an environment in which you can test code with side effects (i.e.: get a memcached instance up and running for this test).

If you do not want this (understandably), it would be better to write your code as a wrapper around the side-effect class in a way that it is mockable. So, your `Foo::__construct` accepts an instance of or factory for the class which produces side effects, so you can mock it in your tests to test only your side-effect-free code.

Comment: Given that I wouldn't want to have to create the dependency and explicitly inject it everywhere I create an instance of this class, would I just make it an optional constructor parameter?  That way the tests could inject a mock, but my normal code could just instantiate like normal and let the constructor create the dependency?

Comment: @drrcknlsn Yes, optional dependency injection is a good strategy IMO. E.g.: `__construct(Memcached $m = null) { if (!$m) $m = new Memcached; }` It cuts down the injection madness while still maintaining the advantages.

Comment: +1 Simplified testing is one of the benefits of [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you should be more concerned with testing the methods that helper() calls and less concerned with bar() in this case.

Sometimes when a method does a lot of things, it's good to break it up and have other methods do those things. When you do this, you expect the same output as before, but the code is broken up into more manageable pieces. It's important to test the littlest pieces first. When you get to testing bar(), you won't need to test it as much, so you won't have to mock it over and over again. Because a lot of the cases will be covered in the supporting methods of helper().